# Null Pointer Exception in for loop with an array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, methods, constructor, nullpointerexception

Why am I getting this Null Pointer Exception when I run the driver for the Average constructor:

```
  public Average()
  {
    int[] data = new int[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      score = input.nextLine();
      int value = Integer.parseInt(score);
      data[i] = value;


    }
    selectionSort();
    calculateMean();

  }
```

The Average constructor runs fine until the calculateMean and selectionSort methods are called.

```
  public void calculateMean()
  {
    int num;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      num = data[i];
      sum += num;

    }
    mean = sum/data.length;
```

```
  public void selectionSort()
  {
    int maxValue;
    int maxIndex;
    for (int startScan = 0; startScan < (data.length-1); startScan++)
    {
     maxIndex = startScan;
     maxValue = data[startScan];

     for(int index = startScan + 1; index < data.length; index++)
     {
        if (data[index] > maxValue)
        {
          maxValue = data[index];
          maxIndex = index;
      }
    }
    data[maxIndex] = data[startScan];
    data[startScan] = maxValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Both of the methods give null pointer exception and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` seems to be a local variable in the constructor, rather than a field.
I assume that since it does compile without errors, you have a field named data of type int[] that is uninitialized and shadowed by the local array in the constructor, and because of that the field `data` remains uninitialized (and thus, `null`)

Have a look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)